# Remove all the elements but keep 1 element with data-id = x using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The only way to make this question clear is to give you an example.

I have a list of elements on my HTML page. Each element has its own `data-id`, and there are some duplicate values.

I need to use jQuery to remove all the elements but keep 1 element that has the `data-id= x`. `x` is the number of `data-id=…`.

so for example:

I have a `data-id="44444"`

I need to delete all the elements from my page (including the duplicated ones) but keep 1 element which has the `data-id="44444"`

Here is what I have so far:

```js
   var seen = {};
  $('.myLi').each(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if (seen[dataId])
        $(this).remove();
  else
        seen[dataId] = true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="deviceList" class="deviceList">
 
 <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="476444" class="myLi" data-id="476444">476444</li>
 
  
</ul>
```

My current code only removes the duplicated elements but I don't know how to delete/remove all the elements and keep the one with the `data-id="44444"`.

Could someone please advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Get rid of all data-ids you do not want
$('.myLi').not('[data-id="44444"]').remove();
// Clean up the extras
$('.myLi').each((n, el) => {
  if (n > 0) {
    $(el).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="deviceList" class="deviceList">

  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>

  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>

  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>

  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>

  <li data-device-id="476444" class="myLi" data-id="476444">476444</li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I finally think that 2 lines are better and more understandable than a loop function :)

Based on your actual logic:

- I use `parseInt` to manipulate ints in your functions (since there are casted into string by data attribute)
- I loop over each `li`, remove it if not the right it OR if we already kept the first one.

```js
var keep = function (keepId) {
  // remove all with wrong ID
  $('.myLi').not('[data-id="' + keepId + '"]').remove();
  
  // only keep first one if there are many
  $('.myLi').not(':eq(0)').remove();
}

keep(44444)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="deviceList" class="deviceList">
 
 <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234</li>
 
 <li data-device-id="476444" class="myLi" data-id="476444">476444</li>
 
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the lis.  Then for each element, find all the lis with the same data-id and get the ones that are not the first of that data-id, then remove them.

```js
var $lis = $('.myLi');

$lis.filter(function(){
  return !$lis.filter(`[data-id="${this.dataset.id}"]`).first().is(this);
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="deviceList" class="deviceList">
  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444 1</li>
  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444 2</li>
  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234 1</li>
  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234 2</li>
  <li data-device-id="476444" class="myLi" data-id="476444">476444</li>
</ul>
```

Or if I'm misunderstanding and you want *only* the single li.

```js
var $lis = $('.myLi');
$lis.not($lis.filter('[data-id="44444"]').first()).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="deviceList" class="deviceList">
  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444 1</li>
  <li data-device-id="44444" class="myLi" data-id="44444">44444 2</li>
  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234 1</li>
  <li data-device-id="4234" class="myLi" data-id="4234">4234 2</li>
  <li data-device-id="476444" class="myLi" data-id="476444">476444</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, you're the OP. Sorry.  What is my answer doing that is not want you want?  Edit: Are you wanting the end result to *only* contain the one 44444 li?